# Overlapped text in an edit box WIN32

Tags: c++, winapi

I've painted the background color of an edit box with `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` and now when inputting/adding text , it is overlapping. How avoid this?

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
        {
            if(IDC_TEXT1 == GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam))
                {
                    textArea1Brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(198, 226, 255));
                    SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
                    return(LONG)textArea1Brush;
                }

            break;

        }
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Since you set the background mode to transparent, each time the text draws, it treats the previous text as the background. If you want the text to draw over a clean background, you need to draw a clean background.

Comment: The way you create brush will create GDI leaks. Also, your return value is unusual. If this handler is in your dialog box then you should `return (INT_PTR)textArea1Brush;` or `(LRESULT)textArea1Brush;`. Aside from that your logic is correct. I have tested it in a fresh project and everything worked: edit control had light blue brush and text looked fine. If you have follow up questions leave a comment and I will try to help. Best regards.

Comment: Changing return values didn't help. Actually text overlap occurs when text fills up the visible area and you're scrolling up/down OR when you delete some characters and write another instead.

Comment: Did you actually try to draw a clean background as Raymond suggested?